# Jquery background-image not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have a dynamically created list of items. Mouseenter these items and their information appears in a box (in this case `class='pic_box'`).  Initially, the background-image of `.pic_box` is set as a picture of the first item in the list.

Using jquery, I change some text in the box and change the background-image.  Works fine in Chrome and Firefox.  In Safari the text changes, but the background image doesn't update.

A List Item:

```
<table id='inner_table_6' class='inner_table'>
<tr><td class='table_name'>Test Six Apartments</td></tr>
</table>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#inner_table_6').mouseenter(function(){link_enter(6, 'Test Six Apartments', '21', 'test_pic_4.jpg');});
    $('#inner_table_6').mouseleave(function(){link_leave(6, 'Test Six Apartments', '21', 'test_pic_4.jpg');});
});
</script>
```

.pic_box:

```
<div class="pic_box" style="
    background-image:url('images/pictures/6/21/test_pic_4.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;">
    <span id="pic_box_name">Test Six Apartments</span>
</div>
```

the javascript function:

```
var link_enter = function ($id, $apt_name, $pic_id, $pic_name){
    $('#pic_box_name').html($apt_name);
    $('.pic_box').css('background-image', 'url(images/pictures/'+$id+'/'+$pic_id+'/'+$pic_name);
}
```

I thought maybe it was because Safari really wanted some quotes around the url so I tried this:

```
$('.pic_box').css('background-image', 'url("images/pictures/'+$id+'/'+$pic_id+'/'+$pic_name+'"');
```

It gave me the same results, works in Chrome and Firefox and not Safari.

I also tried to not set the background-image initially on page load, but that didn't help either, it would remain blank in Safari and update in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You must be close your url brackets.

```
'url("images/pictures/'+$id+'/'+$pic_id+'/'+$pic_name+'")'
```